# android listactivity onCheckedChangeListener

Tags: android, listview

I'm developing an app and I have one `ListActivity`, which has choice mode set to `choice_mode_multiple`. now i want to override method, which is called when one item is *checked/unchecked*, and I've found out that `onCheckChanged()` method is implemented only for `RadioGroup` and compund `Button`. how can I override something like this in `ListActivity`? or do I have to implement my own `Adapter`? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set onlistitemclick listener to listview , then in itemclick method you can get     mylistView.getCheckedItemCount() , write the code of the operation to be performed.

If this is not clear let me know what you want to implement when item is checked.

```
mylistView = (ListView)customView.findViewById(R.id.mylist);
mylistView.setAdapter(mFolderAdapter);

mylistView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);


mylistView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                        if(mylistView.isItemChecked(arg2)){

  //Dooperation

                            } 
// or 
if(mylistView.getCheckedItemCount()>1){
  //Dooperation
}

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  isItemChecked (int position) or setItemChecked(int position, boolean value) if you using standart array adapter and SINGLE or MULTIPLE choise mode. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#isItemChecked(int)

Also you can create your custom adapter and inflate row layout with checkbox that can hold onClickListener and CheckedChangedListener. 
Use search to find example.

Comment: and i should call isItemChecked in onItemClick?