# Items selected in listview with checkbox

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

How do i get the selected items in my listview with check box, i search for an answer to this but nothing is clear enough for me to under stand

here's my listview

```
public void laptopTab() {
        List<String> listDisplay = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int counter = 0 ; counter<laptopFilter.length;counter ++) {
            listDisplay.add(laptopFilter[counter]);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.filter_listview, 
                R.id.filter_name,listDisplay);

        laptopLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.laptopLV);
        laptopLV .setAdapter(adapter);
        laptopLV.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
```

and here is my code for my onItemClickListener

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position ,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v != null) {
            cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById( R.id.cb ); 
            cb.setChecked(!cb.isChecked());
        }
        switch (th.getCurrentTab()) {
        case 0:
            if(cb.isChecked()){
                th.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1).setEnabled(false);
                th.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(2).setEnabled(false);
                selectedFromLaptopList.add(laptopLV.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            }

            else {
                th.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1).setEnabled(true);
                th.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(2).setEnabled(true);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if(cb.isChecked()){
                th.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0).setEnabled(false);
                th.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(2).setEnabled(false);
                selectedFromMp3List.add(mp3LV.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            } else {
                th.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0).setEnabled(true);
                th.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(2).setEnabled(true);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if(cb.isChecked()){
                th.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0).setEnabled(false);
                th.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1).setEnabled(false);
                selectedFromMobileList.add(mobileLV.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            } else {
                th.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0).setEnabled(true);
                th.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1).setEnabled(true);
            }
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

i have a listview inside a tabhost so i just have to disable the other tab if one checkbox is selected on a current tab

and i have a button. there i want to know all items selected on the listview

please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use the code or answer  mention in the link [android listactivity onCheckedChangeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051813/android-listactivity-oncheckedchangelistener/12052585#12052585) and also make use of `mListview.getCheckedItemPositions()`

Comment: Yeah , you need to use conditions .

Comment: i put laptopLV.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); in my code. My checkbox doesn't check when i click multiple boxes

Comment: have you overridden  the correct method . What is the cb in your code, if you use `laptopLV.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);` then you dont need another checkbox

Comment: what will i use to identify if the listview is selected? but ordinary textView will do?

Comment: Try my code , every thing is there . You need just use the code according to your requirement. Use the api's .  Read the linked question and answer . or in the overridden method use listview api's . You need to try with the existing api's

Comment: Ok wait i'm gonna try. can an ordinary textview will do?

Comment: Will i use checkedTextView for the layout?

Comment: dont use , listview will do every thing for you . if you use `laptopLV.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);` no need to use external layouts .

Comment: i tried to put that code but when ever i click my listview only one checkbox is checked and the other checkbox doesn't change their states after clicking the item what should i do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25131/discussion-between-rahul-patil-and-user1708134)