# how to add one checkbox in a listview in android?

Tags: android

I want to add just one checkbox in a listview, I was researching and just found how to make it with checkbox in all its rows but I want it in just one row.

Thanks in advance

--edit--

thank you @Gaurav, I was researching and I could do it but now when I try to click the item with the checkbox it wasn't clicked

BaseAdapter

```
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    View v = arg1;
    if(arg1 == null){
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inf.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }
    Articulos art = items.get(arg0);
    TextView nombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvNombreRow);
    nombre.setText(art.getNombre());
    CheckBox check = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chkCuadroRow);
    check.setChecked(art.getEstado());
    if(art.getVisible()){
         check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    return v;
}
```

Main

```
ArrayList<Articulos> arrayList = new ArrayList<Articulos>();
    Articulos articulos;
    articulos = new Articulos("Color de fondo",false,false);
    arrayList.add(articulos);
    articulos = new Articulos("Vencimiento de bonos",false,false);
    arrayList.add(articulos);
    articulos = new Articulos("Comparte esta aplicacion",false,false);
    arrayList.add(articulos);
    articulos = new Articulos("Visualizador de tiempo",true,true);
    arrayList.add(articulos);
    articulos = new Articulos("Configuración",false,false);
    arrayList.add(articulos);
    articulos = new Articulos("Tutorial",false,false);
    arrayList.add(articulos);
    articulos = new Articulos("Acerca de",false,false);
    arrayList.add(articulos);
    articulos = new Articulos("Salir",false,false);
    arrayList.add(articulos);

    BaseAdapterCustom adapter = new BaseAdapterCustom(this, arrayList);
    lstConfiguracion.setAdapter(adapter);
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: What you need is a listViewAdapter. In its getView, make your test to know which view you want to inflate.

Comment: please elaborate more what u want

Comment: @DamienR. is current on the base of position we can do this

Comment: @Gaurav for example: I want a listview with 10 or more items but in the 5 position it needs to have a checkbox, only that item.

Comment: added a answer have u got it or not.or what u have done up to now post the code so that we can help u more properly

Comment: yeah, I will comment it, I am trying in this moment using BaseAdapter :)

Comment: i prefer to use check.setVisibility(View.GONE) to check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: this is multiple choice or single choice

Comment: it is single choise and I changed it to View.GONE and still didn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the BaseAdapater Class in the getView u can try this

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
         if(position = yourcondtion){
            //set the visibility of the checkbox true or false
         } 
            return vi;
        }
```

For checked checkbox try this

```
 CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.Checkbox);
        checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
```

Comment: this will make it checked when it is not checked

Comment: that is not the problem, I can set the checkbox checked or not, but when I try to touch the row with the checkbox it doesn't click.

Comment: i am not getting what u want to ask me please explain it more so that i can help u or mail me if u can

Comment: in this [first picture](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43966800/Screenshot_2013-08-29-04-12-10.png) the row what I clicked is in blue obviously
but in the [second](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43966800/Screenshot_2013-08-29-04-12-25.png) I try to click it and it doesn't click.

Comment: see this might help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051813/android-listactivity-oncheckedchangelistener/12052585#12052585

Comment: but I have the onClickListener, what happens is that the row with checkbox doesn't select

Comment: I got it solved. Just had to set focusable and focusonTouchMode properties of checkbox to false.[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859134/listitem-click-doesnt-work-with-checkboxes-android) @Gaurav I could do it thanks to you

Comment: don't tell that, you help me with the baseAdapter without it I wouldn't have been able to start so thanks @Gaurav

Comment: if u think it's u r kindness u r always welcome for any help let me know