# Handling onItemClick event with ListView and complex layout

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout, checkedtextview, onitemclick

This is a request for a best practice for handling the views in the onItemClick events in a ListView.

Each view in my ListView contains an ImageView, some TextViews, and a CheckBox wrapped in a RelativeLayout. On the item view being selected anywhere, I'd like to have the checkbox ticked/unticked as required. I would also like to have the option to change the view style i.e. so the item is highlighted by colouring the stroke.

My current issue is similar to everyone else who does this. Due to ListView recycling, if I grab the View passed into onItemClick and set the backgroundresource or checkbox checked value, it also changes them for Views that aren't currently rendered. I'd like to know the best way to achieve this goal.

I know there is a pattern to handle the CheckBox events in the ArrayAdapter directly by implementing an onClickListener, but I believe this will only respond to direct selection of the CheckBox; it will ignore any clicks on the rest of the view. Plus, if the CheckBox onClick event is fired, it will consume the click event so onItemClick won't fire, which I need to set my data.

Also, using CheckedTextView will not work since it is inside the RelativeLayout, which won't pass the checked event to the ListView. There was a post where it was recommended to create your own CheckedViewLayout that implements Checkable to handle the View checked events. If I go ahead with this, will I be able to reference my new layout class in xml, or would I then have to design each of my views again but in Java code?

If anyone else has a better solution, then please let me know.

Comment: if true , change only the bg of positon


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051813/android-listactivity-oncheckedchangelistener/12052585#12052585

Comment: Given Answer by @Mit Bhatt will work for you,OnItemClick and chkbox onClick will work because they use Chkbox click in View Holder class like holder.name.setOnClickListener.(In AdpterView)So it will surely solve your problem.

Comment: MDroid, it won't. See my response. Remember, I also have an ImageView in there. This is essentially a phone contacts ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I created my own CheckableRelativeLayout that implemented Checkable and used it as the main container for each ListView item. I used a Boolean value within CheckableRelativeLayout  to track whether the view was clicked or not.

If required, I can post the final class.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I think this link may be useful to you,there is a details for you

[Android ListView Checkbox Example - OnItemClickListener() and OnClickListener()](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html)

Comment: Are you saying onItemClick will still fire even if you attach an OnClickListener to the checkbox? Also, the checkbox is only a small part of my layout. I want to be able to select anywhere on the view not just on the checkbox.

Comment: Try this code once..! It is working from my side,You said that there is a problem because of relative layout,They use Relative layout,!

Comment: Ok, but this will only handle clicks events on the CheckBox. If I click on the TextView, it won't work, right?

Comment: Yeah right, You also want to apply some actions on Textview? In your customlist view?

Comment: Then there is a property of checkbox Text property, you need to Add your text there instead as set textView.

Comment: I essentially want to be able to click anywhere in my RelativeLayout and have onItemClick call, but also be able to change CheckBox state, view style, etc. Currently, recycling prevents me from doing this.

Comment: I've done plenty of the R part. Coming here is last resort. I guess my only option is to create my own RelativeLayout implementing Checkable.

Comment: android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"  Add this to your Checkbox and let me know once pls